# Represent List<E> as SortedMap<Integer,E> in Java?

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons-collection, guava

Is there any wrapper in popular collection libraries, which implements wrapper for `List<E>` so that it can be accessed both with `List<E>` and `SortedMap<Integer,E>` interfaces?

The goal is to have indexes shifted on insert operation and autogenerated on add operation

Comment: I don't think there's such collection. What would be its benefit?

Comment: I want to combine this collection and normal `SortedMap` into one with CombinedCollection

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` provide these functionalities: appending (what you meant by autogeneration on add operation) is obviously possible and indexes are shifted when you do `add(int index, E element)`.